# Laravel - Presentación de información

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente pantalla:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label requerido">{{ trans('message.empresas.contacto_1') }}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="contacto1" id="contacto1" class="form-control text-uppercase" value="{{ old('nombre1', $data['empresa']['contacto1'] ?? '') }}" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label requerido">{{trans('message.empresas.correo_1')}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="email" name="correo1" id="correo1" class="form-control text-uppercase" value="{{ old('nombre3', $data['empresa']['correo1'] ?? '') }}" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label requerido">{{trans('message.empresas.contacto_2')}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="contacto2" id="contacto2" class="form-control text-uppercase" value="{{ old('nombre2', $data['empresa']['contacto1'] ?? '') }}" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label requerido">{{trans('message.empresas.correo_2')}}</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
            <input type="email" name="correo2" id="correo2" class="form-control text-uppercase" value="{{ old('nombre4', $data['empresa']['correo2'] ?? '') }}" required/>
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

al visualizarla se ve así y controlo los campos obligatorios de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El tema es el siguiente, procedo a ingresar un dato de los cuatro que tengo y el color de campo (rojo) que indica que es obligatorio ya no aplica a los demás campos que todavía no se han ingresado.

Cómo se puede hacer este tema para que sigan en rojo los campos que todavía no se han ingresado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

**PONER LOS CAMPOS OBLIGATORIOS EN ROJO DESDE LARAVEL **

A) Colocas la rutina de validacion en el metodo del controlador que esta llamando a la vista, que puede ser en este caso store()

**1) DEBES colocar en la cabecera de la clase controlador el uso del validator.**

```
<?php

namespace cursos\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator; // validacion
```

**2) El contenido del metodo store() debe ser algo como este:**

```
  public function store(Request $request) 
       {     
         // validacion sin redireccion automatica
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'=>'required|alpha_num|min:4',                   
            'email'=>'required|email|unique:user_admin,email',
            'password'=>'min:4|alpha_num',                     
         'password_confirmation'=>'min:4|alpha_num|same:password',
          ]);

      // en caso de error validacion (envia error y campos old() )
                    if ($validator->fails()) {
                        return back()
                                    ->withErrors($validator)
                                    ->withInput();
                    }

                    // Guardar Objeto
                    $User_admin = new User_admin(); // Crea objeto
                    // carga los valore de los campos 
                    $User_admin->name = $request->input('name');
                    $User_admin->email = $request->input('email');
                    $User_admin->password =  bcrypt($request->input('password'));
                    $User_admin->save(); // guarda el registro

                    Session::flash('notificacion', 'Nuevo usuario Admin Registrado');
                    return redirect()->route('RegistrarAdmin');

                }
```

Donde:

```
// validacion sin redireccion automatica
             $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name'=>'required|alpha_num|min:4',                   
                'email'=>'required|email|unique:user_admin,email',
                'password'=>'min:4|alpha_num',                     
             'password_confirmation'=>'min:4|alpha_num|same:password',
              ]);
```

Aqui se coloca los campo con su regla para ser llenado en el formulario

if ($validator->fails()) {
                            return back()
                                        ->withErrors($validator)
                                        ->withInput();
                        }

Este segmento de codigo verifica si se ha validado todos los campos, en caso de cumplir todas las reglas no se ejecuta el contenido del if(), si hay falla en la validacion envia el reporte de los campos que han fallado con los datos viejos para su colocacion en el formulario

```
// Guardar Objeto
                        $User_admin = new User_admin(); // Crea objeto
                        // carga los valore de los campos 
                        $User_admin->name = $request->input('name');
                        $User_admin->email = $request->input('email');
                        $User_admin->password =  bcrypt($request->input('password'));
                        $User_admin->save(); // guarda el registro
```

Este bloque de codigo se encarga de crear el registro, almacenar los campos y guardar los datos.

```
Session::flash('notificacion', 'Nuevo usuario Admin Registrado');
```

Envia una variable de notificacion a la vista indicando que se ha creado un nuevo usuario.

**return redirect()->route('RegistrarAdmin');**

Reenviar nuevamente a la vista del formulario una vez que se ha grabado los datos de manera exitosa.

3) Del lado de la vista es el siguiente codigo y se esta usando Bootstrap para marcar el campo con una clase cuando se encuentra un error de validacion.

```
EL CODIGO ES EL SIGUIENTE:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
  <title></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS  -->
    <link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="text-center">CREAR USUARIOS</h1>
<!-- se copia el bloque form de register -->
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('validacion-formulario.store') }}" id="formulario">
        @csrf
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Nombre</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" >
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Email</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Password</label>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" value="{{ old('password') }}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Confirmar Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password_confirmation" value="{{ old('password_confirmation') }}">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                        Registrar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
</form>

<!-- notificacion de grabado -->
@if (Session::has('notificacion'))
    <h5>{{ Session::get('notificacion') }}</h5>
@endif

 {{-- muestra aviso de error en validacion --}}
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="">
        <h5>Listado de Errores en Validacion</h5>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif


</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

DONDE:

```
 <link href="{{ asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Se llama a bootstrap a traves del helper asset() donde se tiene instalado en /public/vendor.bootstrap/css

```
 <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" >
```

Al input se le coloca la consulta de la variable $errors donde se pregunta si la etiqueta name tiene error por medio de un if tenario, de ser cierto pone la clase "is-invalid" que marca en rojo el campo. (eso se hace en or cada campo que se ha validado)

Tambien tenemos el atributo value="" el cual recibe la entrada de old('name") correspondiente al valor anterior tipeado por el usuario para evitar que vuelva a llenar el campo al ser reenviado.

```
   {{-- muestra aviso de error en validacion --}}
    @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="">
            <h5>Listado de Errores en Validacion</h5>
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Esta seccion de codigo sirve para reportar la lista de errores de validacion encontrados en los campos mediante el recorrido del la variable $error por el @foreache ($error->all() as $error) que contiene devuelve cada item para mostrar en cada `<li> {{ $error }}`

```
  <!-- notificacion de grabado -->
    @if (Session::has('notificacion'))
        <h5>{{ Session::get('notificacion') }}</h5>
    @endif
```

Este codigo muestra una notificacion del controlador indicando que ha sido registrado los datos con exito.